# How to download multiple images from server?

Tags: android, image, download, server

This is my code and `downloadFile(String URLS)` is downloading function.
I am using istagram API to download popular images but just one image is downloaded and the rest of the images are not being downloaded.

How to download images from server?
I knew that there is an issue in `downloadFile(String URLS)` function but I am not able to solve this issue.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mInstagram          = new Instagram(this, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);

        mInstagramSession   = mInstagram.getSession();

        if (mInstagramSession.isActive()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

            InstagramUser instagramUser = mInstagramSession.getUser();

            mLoadingPb  = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_loading);
            mGridView   = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(instagramUser.fullName);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_username)).setText(instagramUser.username);

            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    mInstagramSession.reset();

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                    finish();
                }
            });
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_slideshow))
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            SlideshowActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    finish();

                }
            });

            ImageView userIv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_user);

            DisplayImageOptions displayOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_user)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_user)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_user)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisc(false)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .build();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)                                               
                    .writeDebugLogs()
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayOptions)             
                    .build();

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.init(config);

            AnimateFirstDisplayListener animate  = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

            imageLoader.displayImage(instagramUser.profilPicture, userIv, animate);
            imageLoader.destroy();
            new DownloadTask().execute();

        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {                    
                    mInstagram.authorize(mAuthListener);    
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void showToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private Instagram.InstagramAuthListener mAuthListener = new Instagram.InstagramAuthListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(InstagramUser user) {
            finish();

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error) {     
            showToast(error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            showToast("OK. Maybe later?");

        }
    };

    public static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
        ArrayList<String> photoList;

        protected void onCancelled() {


        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {         
            long result = 0;

            try {
                 params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("count", "10"));
                System.out.println("PARAMS==="+params);

                InstagramRequest request = new InstagramRequest(mInstagramSession.getAccessToken());
                response= request.createRequest("GET", "/media/popular", params);
                System.out.println("RESPONCE VALUE ==="+response);
                rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+"InstagramFavourites";
                rootFileDirectory= new File (rootPath);
                rootFileDirectory.mkdir();


                Log.w("TAG", "Folder Created: " + rootPath);
                System.out.println("IMAGES DOWNLOADED IN FOLDER=="+rootFileDirectory);
                if (!response.equals("")) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj  = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();                   
                    JSONArray jsonData  = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                    int length = jsonData.length();

                    if (length > 0) {
                        photoList = new ArrayList<String>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonPhoto = jsonData.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("low_resolution");

                            photoList.add(jsonPhoto.getString("url"));

                        downloadFile(jsonPhoto.getString("url"));
                            //downloadFile(jsonObj.toString());
                            //downloadFile(photoList.get(i));


                        }

                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) { 

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            mLoadingPb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (photoList == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Photos Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

                int width   = (int) Math.ceil((double) dm.widthPixels / 2);
                width=width-50;
                int height  = width;

                PhotoListAdapter adapter = new PhotoListAdapter(MainActivity.this);

                adapter.setData(photoList);
                adapter.setLayoutParam(width, height);

                mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }     




        void downloadFile(String URLS){
            count=count++;

              HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
               URL url = new URL(URLS.toString());
                System.out.println("URL VALUES"+url);
                 urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //connect
                urlConnection.connect();



String fileName=rootPath+File.separator+"abc"+ count+".png" ;

File fs=new File(fileName);

fs.createNewFile();

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(fs);
                int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                InputStream inputStream;


                if(status >= HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
                {
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
                else
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();           

                //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
                // inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                //this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
                totalsize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                     //   pb.setMax(totalsize);
                    }               
                });


                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;

                while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                    // update the progressbar //
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                           // pb.setProgress(downloadedSize);

//                            float per = ((float)downloadedSize/totalsize) * 100;
//                            System.out.println("Float per value=="+per);
                            //cur_val.setText("Downloaded " + downloadedSize + "KB / " + totalSize + "KB (" + (int)per + "%)" );
                        }
                    });
                }
                //close the output stream when complete //
                fileOutput.close();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // pb.dismiss(); // if you want close it..
                    }
                });         

            } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
                showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);        
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                showError("Error : IOException " + e);          
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (final Exception e) {
                showError("Error : Please check your internet connection " + e);
            }  
            finally
            {
                  urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        void showError(final String err){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), err, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
}


    enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use: [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) its a great library for images on android.

Comment: andDev Thanx for your recommendation but i just want to download images before images displayed in listview

Answer (score 0):

instead of use AsyncTask you would any Image Loader like [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). in loop like

```
for(...)
{
   Bitmap bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync(imageUri);
   // save bitmap here.
}
```

or you can use Download Manager as like [here](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/download-manager-in-android-with-example.html#.VWF5jNKqqko).
you can do same in loop for multiple image download.

Comment: I did not want to use any down loader..i just want to want download images before images displayed in list view

Comment: If you just want to display image, than Universal image loader is best choice, and just try once. And any option you choose, will take a time to get image from internet, the best and faster option is universal image loader.

Comment: i want to download image.images are displayed already.i have problem in downloading images

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), it fast ,easy to use and take care most of the stuff.

Comment: I am using   Universal Image Loader

Comment: I tried every possible solution but some time it give error "enoent no such file or directory android".....and know it's giving an error of inputstream

Comment: Stack trace will be more helpful, because everything looks good. Just one thing you are not closing your 'inputStream' before aborting connection. Please do that and post the stack trace if available.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very late, but still "better late than never!"

This tutorial on using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to download multiple files was of great help to me: [Downloading Multiple Files In Android Using ThreadPoolExecutor](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/06/10/downloading-multiple-filesimages-etc-in-android-simultaneously-in-android-using-threadpoolexecutor/)